# DFS Replication server role and Remote Differential Compression feature

Tags: windows-server-2019, dfs, rdc

In Microsoft documentation about [DFS Replication](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/dfs-replication/dfsr-overview) is written that DFS Replication uses Remote Differential Compression algorithm for efficient data replication. But when you install the DFS Replication, there is still an uninstalled Remote Differential Compression feature.

##### DFS Replication role

[image]

##### Remote Differential Compression feature

[image]

My question is does DFS Replication uses it's own Remote Differential Compression algorithm, separate form the Remote Differential Compression feature that can be separately installed for different purposes, or dose the DFS Replication works less efficiently if the Remote Differential Compression feature is not installed as well? I mean is it like with Domain Controllers, they don't have DFS Namespace and DFS Replication installed as roles, but they actually have them and used them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suspicion is confirmed. **DFS Replication** role has it's own **Remote Differential Compression** separate form the **Remote Differential Compression** feature. Same as **Active Directory Domain Services** role has it's own **DFS Replication** and **DFS Namespace** role. I have created a replication group among two servers that don't have **Remote Differential Compression** feature installed but in the replication connection properties the checkbox for usage of **Remote Differential Compression** is checked and can be unchecked.

[image]